# Prove that a graph is isomorphic with its line graph

Tags: graph-theory

$G\cong L(G)$ iff there is a $r\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $G=C_{i_1}+C_{i_2}+...+C_{i_r}$ , $i_j\ge3$ and $1\le j\leq r$; equivalently, iff for some positive integer $r$, the graph $G$ is a collection of $r$ vertex-disjoint cycles $C_{i_1}, C_{i_2}, \ldots, C_{i_r}$.

I think I have to use that $C_r, r\ge3$ is transitive this means that there is an automorpism $Aut(C_r): s(x)=y$, $x,y \in V(C_r)$

But I'm not really sure how, any ideas on that?

Comment: You may want to explain your notation further. What is $C_i$?

Comment: It's the standard notation for the cycle graph with i vertices

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I see it now, I think I had misread the question. But [and I am not meaning to nitpick here] it would also be helpful to note in the statement of your problem that the $C_i$s are mutually *vertex*-disjoint as opposed to merely edge-disjoint

Comment: ...as the + notation in graph theory can be ambiguous!

Comment: Thank you Mike for observation, I'm not very familiar with graph theory so I'm not aware of such misconseptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mean $G$ is the disjoint union of a set of cycles? Because of this I am just going to assume $G$ is connected to speed things up, the proof for $G$ being disconnected will follow immediately.

We note fairly quick that if $G=C_n$ then $L(G) \cong C_n$ from the definition of a line graph.

Suppose $G \cong L(G)$. By the definition of a line graph, $|V(L(G))|=|E(G)|.$ As $L(G) \cong G$, we also have $|V(L(G))|=|V(G)|,$ thus $|V(G)|=|E(G)|$. As $G$ is connected this implies that $G$ contains exactly one cycle.

We now need to prove that every vertex of $G$ has degree 2. We first note that $G$ cannot have any degree 4 or higher vertices as they will generate cliques of size 4 or higher (and hence extra cycles). Next, we note that the number of vertices of degree 1 must equal the number of vertices of degree 3; this follows as every degree 3 vertex gives a branching path from our main cycle, and every one of these paths must end in a vertex of degree 1 (this can be proved more rigorously by a basic induction argument). Given that $V_n$ denotes the degree $n$ vertices of $G$, and recalling that $|V_1 | = |V_3|$, the amount of edges in the line graph of $G$ is given by the equation
$$ |E(L(G))| = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{n}{2} |V_n| = |V_2 |+ 3 |V_3| \geq |V_1| + |V_2 |+ |V_3| = |V(G)|,$$
with equality if and only if $|V_1| = |V_3| = 0$.
Hence every vertex of $G$ has degree 2 as required.

Comment: Thank you! And also yes $G$ is connected and is also the disjoint union of the cycles $C_n$ sorry I didn't mention that I just started my courses on graph theory and I'm still not too familiar with the way the formal definitions should be written

Comment: @VakiPitsi Glad I could help! I have found that graph theory has a lot of notation but much of it is non-standard. My advice would be that if you are in doubt whether it is clear, just state what your notation means, even if it possibly seems trivial.

Comment: This is plain wrong: why do you claim that $|E(L(G))| = |V(G)|$? The claw graph $K_{1,3}$ is a counterexample. Also there are plenty of graphs with the same number of edges and vertices that are *not* cycles, for instance any tree with an extra edge.

Comment: @Guido I have now (hopefully) fixed the answer. The extra equations (e.g., $|E(L(G))| = |V(G)|$) were not even required, and extra stuff has been added to address that $|V(G)| = |E(G)|$ only guarantees that $G$ contains exactly one cycle.